# React название тэга с заглавной буквы

Tags: reactjs

Есть необходимость добавлять в шаблон тэги с кастомным названием.
Отрендерить тэг `<some></some>` получается. Но тэг `<Some></Some>` реакт воспринимает как компонент и говорит что не может найти такого.
Есть ли возможность отрендерить тэг с заглавной буквой в названии через реакт?

Comment: На всякий случай, по стандарту кастомные теги обязаны иметь дефис в своём названии. Ну и регистр букв в тегах не имеет значения, так что непонятно, чем вам `<some></some>` не угодил

Comment: @andreymal мне тут пришла смешная мысль, что с помощью реакта было бы довольно удобно генерить xml. А он к регистру чувствителен.